# didStartMonitoringForRegion getting called twice for one startMonitoringForRegion

Tags: objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, mkcoordinateregion

I have started region monitoring by calling `startMonitoringForRegion`.But I found that `didStartMonitoringForRegion` is getting called two times also `didEnterRegion` is getting called twice. But I'm calling `startMonitoringForRegion` only once. My code

```
- (void) enableRegionMonitoring:(NSMutableDictionary *)locationInfoDic{

NSLog(@"started Loc Mon");
locMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locMgr setDelegate:self];
NSString *locationId=[[NSString alloc]init];
double latitude=[[locationInfoDic objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
double longitude=[[locationInfoDic objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];
if([locationInfoDic objectForKey:@"key"]){
    locationId=[locationInfoDic objectForKey:@"key"] ;
}else{
    locationId=@"NA";
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D myMonLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
CLRegion *myRegion = [[CLRegion alloc]
                      initCircularRegionWithCenter:myMonLocation
                      radius:100
                      identifier:locationId];
[locMgr startMonitoringForRegion:myRegion
                          desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

}





- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
NSLog(@"Region monitoring started\n%@",[region description]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try debugging. If you don't have the time to figure it out, simply ignore the 2nd `didEnterRegion` . ie If `didEnterRegion` called two times consecutively for same region simply ignore 2nd one.

Comment: This answer doesn't exactly tell why `didEnterRegion` is called twice, and therefore isn't a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
[locMgr startMonitoringForRegion:myRegiondesiredAccuracy
        :kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
```

After this method why you are not stop the updating method try to call stop updating method.I think this will help you.

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: I tried it. didn't work . also I dont think it's related to stopUpdatingLocation. Again I need location data while running my app.